# How can you get the Facebook Places API to show how many people have check in at a venue in the last 3 hours?

Tags: facebook

How can you get the Facebook Places API to show how many people have check in at a venue in the last 3 hours?

Answer (score 0):

None that I'm aware of. The only data you can get from the API is in relation to the authenticated user (themselves and their friends). I've tried the API request though `https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/checkins` but I only receive my own or friends' checkins to that page.

Interestingly, it seems that this is at least available internally as evidenced by `http://m.facebook.com/places/herenow.php?id=PAGE_ID`